# How can I find the number of comparisons in this algorithm?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computational-complexity

```
procedure pair zeros(b1 b2 . . . bn : bit string, n ≥ 2) 
       x := b1
       y := b2
       k := 2
       while k < n and (x ̸= 0 or y ̸= 0)
           k := k + 1
           x := y
           y := bk
       if x = 0 and y = 0 then print “YES” 
       else print “NO”
```

I know that since we start checking from 2 and k < n, while will loop (n-2) times. But we have to multiply it with the number of comparisons. If condition is not inside the while loop, so I do not know if we count the comparisons there. I also might be wrong about what I said. So, please feel welcomed to correct me

Comment: What computation  is this algorithm supposed to do?

Comment: It checks if there are any consecutive pairs of zeros in the string.

The number of comparisons depends on when the algorithm stops. Do you perhaps meant finding the time complexity for the comparison portion of this algorithm?

Comment: The "code" for your 'algorithm" is badly written, even if it was merely intended as a pseudo-code sketch.  The `while` statement should have some indication of where the loop ends.  Mere indentation is a poor way to convey that.  The number of *equality* comparisons done in the loop depends on more context, while the one *inequality* comparison shown there might be done once per loop or not at all depending on how the while-condition is evaluated.

Comment: I am studying Discrete Math from a textbook and I took this algorithm from the book itself. I just cannot understand how to find the number of comparisons. Book asks for the comparisons but I am open to anyone who can explain the time complexity. I know it is O(n). I just dont know why and how we got that

Comment: Please add the title and author etc. of your textbook to the Question.  There appears only to be one loop in your code, the `while` loop (although it is unclear to me where the body of the while statement ends).  How many times will the `while` loop repeat?  How many "comparisons" are done in each repetition?

Comment: It's Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications by Kenneth H. Rosen (7th edition) Question is 2 in Supplementary Exercises of Chapter 3